# Parse version number to vars

Tags: string, parsing, substring, telegraf, processors

using telegraf 1.24.1.
I want to parse a number version (10.2.12) and return as separated vars (major, minor, patch)

No substring option found.

Thanks in advance

No funtionality found

Answer (score 0):

In many cases like this, it is best to check out the [starlark](https://github.com/influxdata/telegraf/tree/master/plugins/processors/starlark) processor. It is a python-like environment where you could split the string and then create fields for each value: major, minor, and patch.